# Deklination des Wortes "jen-"

Tags: grammar, adjective, declension

Wie ist die Deklination des Wortes *jen-*?

**1. Frage:**
Gibt es das Wort *jene* im Plural oder nicht? *(Bitte kleines Beispiel oder einen Link geben.)*

Ist das unten richtig *(falls es einen Plural von* jen- *gibt)*?

```
PLURAL(?)   
Nominativ: jene   guten Hunde
Akkusativ: jene   guten Hunde
Dativ    : jenen  guten Hunden
Genitiv  : jener  guten Hunde
```

**2. Frage:**
Wie ist die Deklination von *jen-* im Singular? *(Bitte bestätigen oder einen Link geben.)*

Ist das Folgende richtig im Maskulinum?

```
SINGULAR    
Nominativ: jener  gute  Mann
Akkusativ: jenen  guten Mann
Dativ    : jenem  guten Mann
Genitiv  : jenes  guten Mannes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ja, die Deklination ist korrekt.

Es handelt sich bei jener/jene/jenes um ein Pronomen. Beachten Sie, dass die Deklination oben nur die männliche Form ist.

Femininum:

```
SINGULAR
Nominativ: jene feine Dame
Akkusativ: jene feine Dame
Dativ:     jener feinen Dame
Genitiv:   jener feinen Dame

PLURAL
Nominativ: jene feinen Damen
Akkusativ: jene feinen Damen
Dativ:     jenen feinen Damen
Genitiv:   jener feinen Damen
```

Neutrum:

```
SINGULAR
Nominativ: jenes harte Brot
Akkusativ: jenes harte Brot
Dativ:     jenem harten Brot
Genitiv:   jenen harten Brots

PLURAL
Nominativ: jene harten Brote
Akkusativ: jene harten Brote
Dativ:     jenen harten Broten
Genitiv:   jener harten Brote
```